# c++ write all values of an array into txt file

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I've defined var like

```
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} 3DPOINT;
```

then, in my code, I set an array that contains 3DPOINT

```
3DPOINT myArray[1280];
```

I properly fill this array and now I need to write each position into txt file.

```
std::ofstream fs("c:\\testvalues.txt");

for (int i=0;i<1280;i++)
    {
        //here I must get array position data and convert it to string
        fs<<myArrayPositionToString<<"\x0D\x0A";
    }

    fs.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a homework problem, but the << operator of fstream does the conversion for you.

```
fs<<myArray[i].x<<"\t"<<myArray[i].y<<"\t"<<myArray[i].z<<endl;
```

The "\t"-s are tabs, you can also use simple spaces if you'd like.

Comment: thanks but I am using VS2010 and compiler gives me an error in myArray.... left of .x must have class/struct/union

Comment: yup, sorry. Edited: not myarray.y[i], but myarray[i].y is the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `operator<<` on your `struct`, you will have to define an `operator<<` function for your structure.

Search StackOverflow for "overloading insertion operator ostream".

Also search the web for "C++ FAQ operator overloading <<".